# binary search tree generator

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I attempted to build a binary search tree builder method. However I think I am missing something. I tested my method with `inOrderPrint` method and a `treeHeigh` method. How my method works is that a root node is the first parameter. The second parameter is another `TreeNode node`. This parameter is a `TreeNode` and the method should rearrange itself to a binary search tree.

My inOrderPrint is giving me the correct printing which leads me to assume that my `buildBST` is working. However my `treeHeight` method is not giving me the correct output. I'm pretty sure my `inOrderPrint` and `treeHeight` methods are correctly created.

I believe there is some logic I am missing in my `buildBST` method but I cant seem to tell what it is.

I have root set as 14.
If I put `TreeNodes` with values `5,10,3,20,50,25,40,1,2, 18, 100,101`, I get a sorted output of those numbers but with `treeHeight`, I get an output of 5 when I should be expecting 7.

Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Binary Search Tree generator
code:

```
public static void buildBST(TreeNode root, TreeNode node) {
        if (root == null) {
            node = root;
        } else {
            // less than root
            if (node.data < root.data) {
                if (root.left == null) {
                    root.left = node;
                } else {
                    buildBST(root.left, node);
                }
            }
            // greater than root
            if (node.data >= root.data) {
                if (root.right == null) {
                    root.right = node;
                } else {
                    buildBST(root.right, node);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

inOrderPrint:

```
public static void inOrderPrint(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            inOrderPrint(node.left);
            System.out.println(node.data);
            inOrderPrint(node.right);
        }
    }
```

treeHeight:

```
public static int treeHeight(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int Ldepth = treeHeight(node.left);
            int Rdepth = treeHeight(node.right);
            return Math.max(Ldepth, Rdepth) + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think is wrong... Did it with pen and paper I get Max Height of 5

Comment: @gtgaxiola With root as 14 and input nodes 5,10,3,20,50,25,40,1,2,18,100,101 I think the height of the tree should be more than 5. Thank you for your effort

Comment: Please test your input in a Visualizer... You will see

Comment: The height of the tree is 5.

Comment: @gtgaxiola could you recommend me one?

Comment: http://www.qmatica.com/DataStructures/Trees/AVL/AVLTree.html  <--- On Options Please Remove AVL (otherwise it will BALANCE the tree)

Comment: With 13 values the depth can be between 4 and 13. This is why there is interest in optimal binary search trees. A naive implementation runs O(n^{3}) and why Knuth's algorithm in O(n^{2}) is a big deal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree#Knuth.27s_Dynamic_Programming_Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

```
                         14
                        /  \
                       5   20
                      /    /\
                     3    18 50
                    /        / \
                   1       25  100
                    \       \   \
                     2       40   101
```

Height is 5.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the tree is most definitely 5. Easy to see using this little tool

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/GrowingTree/